# custom nspredicate to be between two distances

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

Is there a way to narrow my predicate to be between two distances? Currently, all I can create is a predicate that takes in a singular radius and finds all objects within that radius from the user's current location.

```
var locationPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "distanceToLocation:fromLocation:(%K, %@) < %f", "Location", location,
                                        1000)
```

For a visual representation, I would want to grab all objects in the orange part of this drawing, with the center being the user's current location. (I can currently only get yellow AND orange). [image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a `BETWEEN` statement:

```
NSPredicate(format: "distanceToLocation:fromLocation:(%K, %@) BETWEEN { %f , %f }", "Location", location, lowerBound, upperBound)
```

Comment: this doesnt work, and just ends up crashing with an bad predicate exception. any other ideas? I've been trying to find one on my own and not really having much luck.

Comment: Depending on the setup you could always just not use NSPredicates or use block based predicates instead. Is there any relevant information in the crash logs?

Comment: Not familiar with a block based predicate, I'll do some research. The crash logs really just say "invalid predicate" because distanceToLocation:fromLocation really is only supposed to take 1 argument (to the best of my understanding). Perhaps there is a different argument that supports the between function?

Comment: Seems like an issue in your original predicate. I just copied everything except the `< %f` part of your predicate, which I replaced with the between statement.

Comment: Block predicates are explained [here](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/#block-predicates).